# Work out if the numbers are consecutive. For example,"5-6-7-8-9", display: "Consecutive"; otherwise, display "Not Consecutive"

Tags: c#

I am doing a basic string exercise question and my logic is something like this but as it an obvious thing that we can not increment a string value like this `temp++` in my case what should be the solution of this :

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a few numbers separated by a hyphen : ");

var input = Console.ReadLine();

var split = input.Split('-');

var temp = split[0];

for (int i = 1; i < split.Length; i++)
{
    temp++;

    Console.WriteLine(temp);

    if (temp == split[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Consecutive");
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse `temp` to a number. There are many places to find out how.

Comment: if i do `var temp = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);` then i get this error **operator == can not be applied to operand of type int and string**

Comment: ...because `split[i]` is a string. Can you guess what I'm going to say next?

Comment: I'am sorry i didn't get you.

Comment: I mean, think for yourself. If you have two numbers, as strings, and you want to compare them as numbers, what do you do? I've given you the hint that you should parse one of them as a number. Logically, you would need to parse the other as a number as well...

Comment: @EJoshuaS actually what i've done is that i've taken an integer called `temp` and initialized with the value of the `split[0]` and then i want to do increment in the value of `temp` for comparison between `temp` value and the rest of the indexes of split array.

Comment: I'd **strongly** suggest getting rid of all of the instances of "var" in this case and replacing them with their type names. Once you do that I think it'll be easier for you to see what's wrong here. In general, you should only use "var" if the right-hand side makes it really obvious what the type is, and that's just not the case here. For example, contrary to what you stated, temp is **not** an integer, it's a string.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thank you so much i've fixed that by doing this : `temp == int.Parse(split[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
static bool AreConsecutive(IReadOnlyList<int> numbers)
{
  for (var i = 1; i < numbers.Count; ++i)
  {
    if (numbers[i] != numbers[i - 1] + 1)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Then you could go:

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a few numbers separated by a hyphen : ");

var input = Console.ReadLine();

var inputParsed = input.Split('-').Select(int.Parse).ToList();

if (AreConsecutive(inputParsed))
  Console.WriteLine("Consecutive");
```

This will not give a pleasant message in case of bad input (characters that will not parse as integers).

Comment: The following was not written by me, converted from an edit suggestion: User _Drunken Code Monkey_ was in the middle of writing a Linq solution when the question was closed, he will just add it here, hopes this is acceptable:
`int[] set = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 };
bool consecutive = ( set.Aggregate( (x, y) => Math.Abs(x - y) - 1 + y) - set.Last() ) == 0;`


 This uses `.Aggregate()` to walk through the series. The aggregate in a consecutive series will always end up the same value as the last member of the series.

Comment: I debated whether I should put it in a comment, I wasn't sure if the code was going to be readable, sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey Yeah, I also did not know what to do. The code part of your approach is not so long, so I think people can read it from the comment her. Not sure if it fits into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest not using `var` when the right-hand side doesn't make it really obvious what the type is.

Let me rewrite this with the variable types and see if it makes it more clear what the problem is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a few numbers separated by a hyphen : ");

string input = Console.ReadLine();

string[] split = input.Split('-');

// Think about what type this SHOULD be
string temp = split[0];

for (int i = 1; i < split.Length; i++)
{
    // Considering the fact that temp is actually currently a string, why should this work?
    // It's pretty obvious what "1" + 2 would mean, but what would "dog" + 1 mean?
    temp++;

    Console.WriteLine(temp);

    // Consider the fact that these must be the same type to do "==" (or there must be an implicit typecast between them)
    if (temp == split[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Consecutive");
    }
}
```